# Building Twitter app with reactJs, clicking on Profile Button gives error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:20)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

The home page compiles correctly, however when I click the Profile button the error message:

./node_modules/react-native-profile-header/build/dist/ProfileHeader.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

From the link, I tried entering this code in the ProfileHeader module:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

That did not work.

I tried this command in Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
 webpack(config){config.infrastructureLogging = { debug: /PackFileCache/ }
 return config;}
```

That did not work.

Here is my code:

```
import useRouter from 'next/router'
import { BsArrowLeft, BsArrowLeftShort } from 'react-icons/bs'


const ProfileHeader = () => {
    const router= useRouter()
    
    const isProfileImageNft = false 
    const currentAccount = '0xcde6d34dDcB5777540D391C0d075458D9869276C'
    
})
  
return (
    <div className= {style.wrapper}>
    <div className= {style.header}>
    <div onClick={() => Router.push('/')} className= {style.backButton}>
    
        <BsArrowLeftShort />
     </div>
    <div className= {style.details}>
    <div className= {style.primary}>Dustin Car</div>
    <div className= {style.secondary}>4 Tweets</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div className= {style.coverPhotoContainer}>
        <img
            src= "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRjhZ4NIrmVP96XRp66qmVfu4O1770Hg3udKA&usqp=CAU"
            alert= 'cover'
            className= {style.coverPhoto}
    />
    </div>
        <div className= {style.profileImageContainer}>
        <div className= {isProfileImageNFT ? 'hex' : style.profileImageContainer}>
        
        <img
            src= "'https://d1bvpoagx8hqbg.cloudfront.net/259/ce697834bacdad2949bb49edd98bea34.jpg'" 
            alt= "Dusty"
            className= {
                isProfileImageNFT? style.profileImageNft : style.profileImage
            }
            />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className= {style.details}>
        <div>
            <div className= {style.primary}>Dustin Car</div>
            </div>
            <div className= {style.secondary}>
            {currentAccount && (
            <>
              @{currentAccount.slice(0, 8)}...{currentAccount.slice(37)}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        </div>
            <div className={style.nav}>
                <div className= {style.activeNav}>Tweets</div>
                <div>Tweets & Replies</div>
                <div>Media</div>
                <div>Likes</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default ProfileHeader
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In another module where I imported Profile Header, the file path was incorrect.

The incorrect path was:
import ProfileHeader from 'react-native-profile-header'

The correct file path is:
module "/Users/dcarav77/twitterblockchainapp/twitter-clone-blockchain/pages/components/ProfileHeader"